# mvc:view-controller causes PageNotFound in Spring Tiles2

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, dispatcher, tiles2

I have a webapp based on Spring 3.0.6 which works fine on Tomcat 7.0.

The `web.xml` defines the dispatcher as following:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The dispatcher defines the view resolver in the usual way:

```
<bean id="tilesViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
  <property name="viewClass"
      value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView" />
</bean>

<bean id="tilesConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
  <property name="definitions">
    <list>
      <value>/WEB-INF/tiles-def.xml</value>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

I have a controller annotated with `@RequestMapping("/home")` and a `"home"` view defined in `tiles-def.xml`. When I point my browser to the `/myapp/home.html`, the Tiles page is opened.

If I add `<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />` or `<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="home.html"/>` to my dispatcher xml file, pointing the browser to `/myapp/home.html` results in a 404. The log says:

```
21:34:22,128  WARN PageNotFound:947 – No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/myapp/home.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You can set a breakpoint in DispatcherServlet.doDispatch and see what's going on. :)

Comment: Hi Boris, I tried to debug but the internal working of the dispatcher servlet was pretty complex to understand. The problem was that the method in my MVC Controller was `void` and did not return any string, so the framework tried to resolve the view automatically using the path. I changed this returning explicitly the Tiles2 view name, and everything worked again. I learned the lesson, never let Spring guess anything... ;-)

Comment: Ok. Please post your results as an answer and close the question )).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in my application was due to the *automatic* view name resolution. My annotated method in my `@Controller` returned `void`, and the framework tried to guess the tiles view name using the request path.

I modified my annotated method as following, returning a `String`:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/page", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showForm(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
    // TO BUSINESS LOGIC

    // return tiles view name as configured in 'tiles-def.xml'
    return "my_tiles_view_name";
}
```

With this change, everything works fine.